# R: Row sums by same column patterns

Tags: r, matrix, sum

I'm trying to merge columns and calculate row sums which with same defined string pattern.

For example:

```
mat <- matrix( 1:20, nrow = 2, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(mat) <- c("slurry","slurrys","liquid","liquids","solut","solution","aqueou","aqueous","agent","agents")

mat
     slurry slurrys liquid liquids solut solution aqueou aqueous agent agents
[1,]      1       2      3       4     5        6      7       8     9     10
[2,]     11      12     13      14    15       16     17      18    19     20
```

I want to get the following result:

```
     slurry liquid solut aqueou agent
[1,]      3      7    11     15    19
[2,]     23     27    31     35    39
```

I have tried use sapply to do, but the calculate result is wrong.

```
nams <- c("slurry", "liquid", "solut","aqueou", "agent")
nams_bind <- sapply(nams, function(i)rowSums(mat[, nams==i, drop=FALSE]))

nams_bind
     slurry liquid solut aqueou agent
[1,]      7      9    11     13    15
[2,]     27     29    31     33    35
```

Is any way to revise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to subset the columns based on patterns as the `==` will look for exact match

```
sapply(nams, function(x) rowSums(mat[,grep(x, colnames(mat))]))
#     slurry liquid solut aqueou agent
#[1,]      3      7    11     15    19
#[2,]     23     27    31     35    39
```